# add custom control with image to wpf Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have this project where I would like to set some images to my screen by adding a custom control (inSignalLight) to a listbox (or some other control, I would just like to line them up). I have set the images in the custom controls and added them to a "ObservableCollection", but nothing shows up. Im really new to WPF, so not quite sure if the xaml is corrent... If there is a better way to do it then in a listbox, please tell me so too.

```
inSignalLights = new ObservableCollection<inSignalLight>();
```

Here is the xaml in the page that I would like to show the pictures in.

```
<Page x:Class="Project.Pages.MainPicView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 

  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  Background="Beige"
Title="MainPicView" d:DesignHeight="343" d:DesignWidth="676">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label Content="Label" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,195,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=inSignalLights}" Width="400" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Edit:

This is the xaml for the custom control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.CustomControls.inSignalLight"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="16" d:DesignWidth="16">
<Grid>
    <Image Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="signalImage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Edit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inpins; i++)
        {
            InPin ip = iFace.getInPin(i);
            parent.insertNewSignalLight(ip);
        }

public void insertNewSignalLight(InPin ip)
    {
        inSignalLight isl = new inSignalLight(ip);
        isl.setLightOff();
        this.inSignalLights.Add(isl.signalImage);
    }
public void setLightOff()
    {
        setThreadSafeImage(signalImage);
    }

    private void gotLightSignal(InPin pin, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Join(200);
        if (pin.PinState == 1)
            setLightOn();
        else
            setLightOff();
    }
    public void setThreadSafeImage(Image iS)
    {
        string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/;component/Images/Signal_Gron_16.png");
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
        img.Freeze();

        iS.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(() => iS.Source = img));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have `ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images`  in your ViewModel.
I think your UserControl with Image is unnecessary.

You must define ItemTemplate in ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" Width="400" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And how to fill collection Images? It's very easy.
Add BitmapImage instances in loop like:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"/Images/image_file.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
```

Comment: Hello, I changed it do its now ObservableCollection<ImageSource> instead, but nothing shows up on in the listbox.. I edit my code to show how I add!

Comment: No idea :(. Look into Output window in visual studio or try change DispatcherPriority.DataBind.

Comment: You can't use signalImage. It's not correct.... Your collection (ItemsSource) is observablecollection<ImageSource> Images. If you want to change the image, you must have to change ... some item in observablecollection.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually in your case (if your control stays that simple), you don't need a `CustomControl`, btw your example is IMHO called `UserControl`, anyways.

You can simply declare a `DataTemplate`. E.g.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionInDataContext}"...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding SomePropertyOfYourItemVm1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfYourItemVm2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

For more information please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx).

`UserControls` (composition of controls) and `CustomControls` (extend an existing control) should only be used, if there is no other possibility to implement the desired feature. [This](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html) is a good articel about both types of controls.